# EMP system configuration 11.2.5 Deploy to application application server error

Tags: oracle, essbase

Last two days am facing an error while installing Oracle Essbase installation. I followed below steps

1. I have already installed the oracle database 12c.
2. I have download the file from this link https://www.oracle.com/middleware/technologies/epm-hyperion-foundation-services-downloads.html
3. I have selected configuration -> Hyperion foundation -> Configure common settings, configure the database, Deploy to the application server
4. Configure common settings, configure database installed successfully.
5. Deploy to the application server is showing an error

for reference I have added a screenshot, please help me to figure out this issue.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is a missing @ that should precede hostName.  Without the @, the EPM System Configurator will complete but Foundation Service will not start due to Invalid URL.

1] Please modify the RCUSchema.properties file using unencrypted password and DB URL as follows:

Oracle Database with SID:
jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostName:port:sid

Oracle Database with service Name:
jdbc:oracle:thin:@//hostName:port/serviceName

2] Copy the below file F:\Oracle\Middleware\oracle_common\modules\oracle.jps\domain_config\jse\system-jazn-data.xml
to folder F:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domain\EPMSystem\config\fmwconfig

3] Rerun the configuration as ADMINISTRATOR